# DT::datatable(iris) gives error in console "Failed to load resource: A server with the specified hostname could not be found."

Tags: r, rstudio

(I could not see a tag for "r DT")

I've used datatable many times before. What appears like out of the blue, any tables I created using datatable now won't render.

Taking the simplest example from documentation:

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris)
```

In R Studio a blank viewer pane in all white is displayed. When I look in the console I see an error message:

> Failed to load resource: A server with the specified hostname could not be found.

```
packageVersion("DT")
[1] ‘0.2’
```

Here's are screen shots of my rstudio:
Blank viewer pane:
[image]

And after I right click on inspect element and view the console tab (not sure if this is relevant or not):
[image]

Does anyone know how I can get DT to render my datatables?

Comment: There’s a data.table package and a DT package. Are you trying to interface with an external installation of DataTables using DT or are you misspelling data.table?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to render a visually appealing table using DT package, not the data wrangling data table package. I also just found this relevenat discussion but there appears to be no solution: https://community.plot.ly/t/rstudio-viewer-shows-blank-plots-the-browser-can-show-them-though/3359

Comment: DT requires external resources that you have not mentioned.

Comment: @42, I'm not following, could you clarify?

Comment: Since posting this question I've changed location and am now using my home wifi as opposed to my personal hotspot earlier. Now, for whatever reason, all of the tables are rendering in the viewer. When I was working from mobile hotspot I did experiment by switching of the internet to my laptop while running the commands but no effect.

Comment: There is a JavaScript library called DataTables. The DT package (in R) is an interface to that (external) package. One would need to have the external components properly installed or referenced and you make no mention of your specific installation.